# Error al intentar crear función almacenada para encontrar los cuartiles en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando crear una función almacenada en mysql para obtener los cuartiles de un conjunto de datos pero al intentar crear la tengo el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION obtenerCuartil(q DOUBLE)
    RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE t BIGINT DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dataCsv);
    DECLARE pos INT;
    DECLARE cuartil INT;
    IF q = 0.25 THEN
        SET pos = (((t+1)*1)/4);
        SET cuartil = (SELECT salario FROM (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(salary AS INT)) AS Posicion, salary AS salario FROM dataCsv)t1 WHERE Posicion = pos);
    ELSE IF q = 0.5 THEN
        SET pos = (((t+1)*2)/4);
        SET cuartil = (SELECT salario FROM (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(salary AS INT)) AS Posicion, salary AS salario FROM dataCsv) t1 WHERE Posicion = pos);
    ELSE IF q = 0.75 THEN
        SET pos = (((t+1)*3)/4);
        SET cuartil = (SELECT salario FROM (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(salary AS INT)) AS Posicion, salary AS salario FROM dataCsv)t1 WHERE Posicion = pos);
    END IF;
        RETURN cuartil;
END$$
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión exacta de MySQL está ejecutando? *SQL window functions* son soportadas desde la versión 8.0.2 de MySQL.

Comment: esta usando la version 7. Despues lo probe en local con la version 8.0.2 de mysql y me da el siguiente error #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 21

Comment: El error mostrado en su comentario ya no parece un problema por las *SQL window functions*. Un par de observaciones: 1) `INT` no es tipo de dato válido para `CAST`, puede usar `SIGNED` o `UNSIGNED` dependiendo lo que realmente necesite. 2) La sentencia `IF` puede tener clausulas `ELSEIF` (sin espacio) no `ELSE IF`.

Comment: ya me funciona. gracias por tu ayuda